# Tight shutter speed but picture still blurry!

Tags: sharpness

I shot indoors under dim lighting and struggled getting sharp quality. 
The image below was shot at: 
1/125   8.0    ISO 3200

My thinking was the ISO was high enough, the shutter speed fast enough and my manual focusing sharp enough for a more focused subject. 
What could I have done to make the subject more in focus and sharper?

[image]

Comment: What was your reasoning for using manual focus and f/8.0?

Comment: What focal length were you using as well?

Comment: What focal length was this shot at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blown out blue/red light making photos look out of focus](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/73453/blown-out-blue-red-light-making-photos-look-out-of-focus)

Comment: The singer's skin is overexposed in the red channel and making her look blurry. Please see the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Crazy Dino- I usually go for manual focus, it's more hands on. Is there something in addition between manual focus and the aperture that I need to consider? Focal length: 26mm!

Comment: Please define ' sharp quality'. Does that mean sharpness or exposure?

Answer (score 1):

In this context I'd have gone as wide open as possible with the aperture.. 2.8 minimum perhaps even 1.8

Shutter speed is probably ok at 1/125 but perhaps using a wider aperture could have allowed you to go for a faster shutter - depends on how much the subject was moving!

The blur here is almost definitely shutter speed I'd guess?

Comment: Oh and I think automatic focus might have helped - again depending on how still the subject was

Comment: I personally focus much better manually than my camera does in low light,    But that is not to say that I focus well in low light all the time.  I need a new camera.